# change timezone in mod_wsgi on openshift

Tags: django, timezone, openshift

I deployed a django application on openshift and I'm running it in productive mode. When I look at the logs (python.log) in $OPENSHIFT_LOG_DIR I see  messages from my django app and the apache server/mod_wsgi.

These two sources use different format of their messages - I know I can change the log format of my django application to use the same format as the apache log, but the two sources are also using different time zones. The django application runs in Berlin/Europe time zone whereas the apache log messages uses Eastern Standard time. This makes it uncomfortable to read the logs:

```
195.195.195.12 - - [25/Oct/2016:15:14:09 -0400] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 404 85 "-" ...
195.195.195.12 - - [25/Oct/2016:15:14:09 -0400] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 404 85 "-" ...
[Tue Oct 25 21:14:09 2016] [error] kwargs in CreateView: {'instance': None, 'prefix':  ...
[Tue Oct 25 21:14:09 2016] [error] ModelForm.__init__ called                           ...
195.195.195.12 - - [25/Oct/2016:15:14:09 -0400] "GET /publisher/upload HTTP/1.1" 200 2 ...
195.195.195.12 - - [25/Oct/2016:15:14:11 -0400] "GET /static/publisher/css/bootstrap/b ...
```

Is there a way I can make apache/mod_wsgi use Berlin/European time zone?

PS: A way to change the format of the apache log format would also be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot change the log format nor override the TZ that Apache itself uses in the OpenShift 2 Python cartridge.